# Why was this question downvoted?

Tags: discussion, voting

Can someone tell me why this question has so many downvotes, and no comments regarding how to improve the question?

[What is the reason behind the current menu structuring](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/43883/what-is-the-reason-behind-the-current-drupal-menu-structuring)

Comment: I'm active on about half a dozen SE sites and Drupal.SE has by far the most drive-by downvotes without any constructive feedback. I don't understand why, either.

Answer (score 1):

From the [FAQ](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/faq):

> Please don't ask any question about these topics. They are out of scope for this site.
>
> - **Comparison between Drupal and other CMS's, blog software, or similar software**
> - Building a site from scratch
> - Issues found in existing modules/themes
> - Issues about drupal.org, or any of its sub-domains
> - Recommendations for Drupal hosting

(emphasis mine).

So questions asking for a comparison between the way Drupal and 2 other CMS's handle something are not on-topic for the Drupal Answers site.

I'm a little (but only a little) surprised that you have 3 downvotes and zero comments (and zero vote-to-close votes for that matter), but don't take it personally. I understand it can be frustrating to get downvotes without any constructive criticism, but such voting is anonymous for a reason.

I for one have lost count of the number of times I've tried to leave constructive criticism for somebody and they've taken it in the wrong way, and become quite belligerent about the whole thing. So I now very rarely leave comments when I downvote...it's just not worth the hassle.

Comment: I don't see this is a CMS comparison question, but rather a question about the rationale behind a decision Drupal (and others) made.

Comment: @MPD The question was: _What are the advantages that the Drupal/Joomla method offers?_ That's asking for a comparison between Drupal and Joomla I think. It also asks for a list of advantages/disadvantages, which would also be 'not constructive'

Comment: @MPD Sorry that's not right is it...but the question still asks for a comparison in the rationale behind a decision made in different CMSs (Drupal/Joomla and Wordpress) so I think it's still a comparison of 2 CMSs

Comment: @Clive, I hadn't intended it as a comparison with other framework. I wanted to know the reason behind the Drupal decision. What made me ask it is, is what I wanted to point out by telling about other frameworks. I think like constructive criticism my question was also taken the wrong way.

Comment: @Clive, By the way I'm an active user of stackoverflow. I do understand downvotes and I also do it. But normally when I downvote I try to leave a reason. I personally go for that policy. But I very well understand your choice and know that stackexchange allows it to be anonymous. No way I'm going take it personal. :)

Comment: I guess I need to make some rephrasing in the question, so that its intention is more clear to the general public.

Comment: I have tried my hand in making the question clear. If any of you have some better idea at making the idea behind the question more clear and with less confusion, please do it. Its a humble request.

Comment: @saji89 That's a lot clearer :) I think it's quite a difficult question to answer unless some of the original decision makers happen to see the question, but I hope you get a good answer for it

Comment: @Clive, Thanks. I also hope to get some good solid answers.